# Cartoon/puzzle mini games where the objective was to blow up a tower, kill someone etc

Tags: story-identification, cartoon, video-games

I found this franchise when it was around **2002-2006**. It just keep stuck in my head until now.

These are some points that I am sure of:

- I am sure it was not anime. It is more of like cartoon-style graphics
- The game is so old that it may be either mini games or mini flash games
- I found it on a site with several episodes in it (I believe around 20-40 ish).
- The graphics were decent enough for that old year compared to - say - mini golf game.
- But I am not sure whether the franchise has movie/cartoon episode
- The themes of the mini game was more like of a military/thriller things, I am sorry I am not that good at recalling the detail
- I am sure that there are at least 2 main characters

  1. First character:

     - A Male
     - Topless-masculine man, who looked like a soldier/special agent for me.
     - My first impression was just like Rambo, but I am sure that it is not Rambo
     - Yellow-brown skin
     - Dark pants (black/brown)
     - Has face paint on his cheek (just like soldier)
     - I believe the hair was blonde/orange
  2. Second character:

     - A white Female
     - Has black colored short hair
     - Looks to me like someone who lacks physical skill but smart in technical skills like hacking, bomb defusing, etc
- The game was typically like walking simulator where you control specific character each level and explore around the environment and solve the puzzle.
- The point of view was far from above, so it is like we move a character and see it from the far top. Something like RTS style, like *Age of Empire*, for example.
- The puzzle though, is like killing some one, or how to pass this river, or how to blow down a tower, something like that.

I searched all cartoon network games, found none. Also searched all mini game/flash game sites that I can think of, still found none.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Although we occasionally do game identification questions, the games should be on-topic here.  Was there anything science fictional or fantastic about the plot of the game?

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! These might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (video game) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11995/how-to-ask-a-good-video-game-story-id-question)

Comment: Was this real-time? Turn based? Was movent on a grid, or more freeform? And do you remember, was positive from directly overhead? 3/4 isometric? Flat tiles? Were you able to switch characters in a level?

Comment: @DavidW Thanks for answering! I believe there are some kind of sci-fi scandal, where the antagonist seems to creating some kind of formula that, if injected into human/animal could make them turn more aggressive, something like that. I believe it is also considered sci-fi.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Thanks!
It was real-time game play. Movement is not a grid (so not like chip's challenge). I believe we can't switch a characters in the same level. But at certain level you can control the Man, and then you get to control the woman on the other level. Something like that.